# Create JLabel Array

Tags: java, arrays, list, label

I have 34 labels with images i can't figure how do i make when ill click the label itself to get selected and in the down right corner that "Selected: " to get changed on every label select.

[image: 34 Labels]

The labels variable names are from `n1 to n34` i have this code so far but in the list `getSelectedNumbers()`

```
List<JLabel> lotteryBoxes = new ArrayList<>();

List<JLabel> getSelectedNumbers() {
    List<JLabel> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<JLabel> it = lotteryBoxes.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        JLabel nr = it.next();
        if (nr.isCursorSet()) {
            numbers.add(nr);
            Selected.setText("Selected: " + nr);
        }
        return numbers;
    }
```

I do not know what to do, please give me some answers.

Comment: please if someone could help me.

Comment: maybe adding a MouseListener click event to every JLabel

Comment: but isn't there any other way of doing that except for 34 times ? and i also need to store them

Comment: You can generate them in a loop

Comment: If you can show me some example please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you create the labels in a loop, you can add a handler to them. Either the same handler that checks which of the labels was clicked, or a separate handler for each one.

Here there is a separate handler for each and the labels are put into an array so you can use them later (outside the loop).

```
int numberOfLabels = 34;
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[numberOfLabels];
for (int index=0; index<numberOfLabels; index++) {
    String labelText = "" + (index + 1);
    final JLabel label = new JLabel(labelText));
    final int labelNumber = index + 1;
    label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // do something, you can use "label" in here, eg:
            selected.setText(label.getText());
            // you have access to the number in "labelNumber"
        }
    });
    somePanel.add(label);
    labels[index] = label; // save the label if you need to access it later
}
```

Comment: for what is this `somePanel.add(label);` ? and please if you can make the code to copy and paste because it gives me error at `for (int i=0; i<numberOfLabels; i++) {` it says "illegal start of type" thank you very much

Comment: Since you did not include the code that constructs your JFrame etc I made some assumptions. Mainly that you had some JLabel in a variable called selected where you want to put the number of the clicked label, and a JPanel called somePanel that you attached your labels to. You will need to modify this to match your code.

Comment: yes but i want to store the numbers also so when generated/winning numbers will be available to get both arrays

Comment: Just made a small change so you can access the number directly in the mouseClicked() handler. From here you can add it to some list of winning numbers, or whatever you want.

Comment: thank you but i really don't get it this don't think you are the misstake i'm just maybe too tired but ill try think one more time btw do you have something that i can chat with you directly ? 
Thank you again :)

Comment: also i have one more question for what is this `String labelText = "" + (index + 1);` ?